# How can I update value of the field of the document by userID Field without doc ID in the Firebase collection in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update value of the field's document. I wrote a query but it doesn't work.

```
**//this query is working, I hava a doc Id**
    final CollectionReference _company = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Company')
      ..where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.uid);


      **// But this query is not working, because I have not doc** ID, its doc ID auto gen. ID in firebase
    final CollectionReference _companyAdvert =

        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CompanyAdvert')..where('userId', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.uid)  ;
```

[all the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eIb8.png)

Comment: Hi Zekai, can you please rephrase your question? It's not very clear what you require

Comment: Of course. Firstly, Thank you for your care.

Comment: I'am developing a flutter project base on Firebase. I created a collection that named "Company" and add a field companyImage. Company collection's  names are user id. and other collection name is CompanyAdvert. But CompanyAdvert's doc name is to create by auto generated ID.      If Company wants to change its profile photo, ıts must to update in CompanyAdvert profileImage field. I strived with _companyAdvert varible in my code. But I couldn't. and finally How can I do it and sorry my bad english..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFot-59FcOU130BR8ADg07uONy7vSTLI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ZekaiDemir You can edit your question and rephase it no put it in comment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To update a document field in firestore, you need to write

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('CompanyAdvert')
    .doc(id)
    .update({ 'profileImage': *new profile image* });
```

**You must understand** that to update a firestore document, you must keep a reference of the document id in the document itself. You can think of this as the primary key for the document.
There are two ways to do this.

```
1. Get a reference to the newly created document, and then get the id from the reference. 
   Then update the document with this id

2. Generate a random id locally and use that as the document id.
   You can do this with the [Uuid package][1] on pub.dev
```

The first step goes like this:

```
// first, create a document using the add method

DocumentReference docRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('CompanyAdvert')
    .add(*data*);

// then extract the generated document id

String id = docRef.id;

// then save it back to the document using

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('CompanyAdvert')
    .doc(id)
    .update({'id': id});
```

The second step goes like this:

```
String id = const Uuid().v4();

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CompanyAdvert').doc(id).set(*data*);
// Make sure you add the id as one of the fields to the map data
```

**Note** that the first step incurs a write operation which will count against your total quota for firebase. I recommend you use the second approach

Visit the [FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#updating-documents) to learn more

Comment: I tried this but it not worked that My firebase docs already created. is there anyway update feild without doc ID?

Comment: No, you need an ID to update any document